# What to do when a running Spotify process stops working when put into background in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu, spotify

Sometimes when I forget to run Spotify in background and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> it stops working.

Is there any other way this can be done without killing Spotify?

Answer (score 2):

After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, enter the command `bg` to continue Spotify in the background.